# Simon K firmware when the IMU outputs at 50HZ

Tags: arduino, quadcopter, imu

I am building a Quadcopter using the Sparkfun Razor IMU which outputs the Roll, Pitch and Yaw axes values at 50 Hz, which limits the operations of the controller(implemented on Arduino IMU), to 50 Hz mx itslef. Please tell me if flashing the ESCs(EMax 40A) with the Simon K firmware can do me any good.

I'll be grateful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simonk K firmware can give you ESC update rate upto 400Hz. But your output rate is limited to 50Hz as your control loop cannot run at more than 50Hz.

High ESC update rate will only be hepful when you can run your control loop at higher frequency.

Answer (score 1):

There are benefits from SimonK beyond update frequency. For example SimonK handles hysteresis (The time it takes to change the rpm of the motor is drastically reduced with simonk) differently.

Also it eliminates some of the unwanted parameters that WILL cause you grief, eg lipo cutoff and brakes.

Using a 50mhz update rate will not produce a very good performance multirotor. The Razor does processing on board, which will be repeated by the flight controller. Something like a $25 Naze would be magnitudes better.